# Excel Groupings and math

Tags: excel

I have an Excel Sheet that looks like the below. I am trying to calculate the match for each customer

```
Sheet1
Customer Name | Type | Price | Fee
Bob, Hammer, 5.00, .10
Sam, Pencil, 1.00, .20 
Bob, ToolBox, 50.00, .30 
Sam, ScrewDriver, 5.00, .40
```

What I want is to calculate the information on Sheet 2 of total Cost and buy

```
Sheet2
Customer Name | Total Profit | Average Profit 
Bob, 55.40, 27.7
Sam, 6.6, 3.3
```

Would Formula fields be the best approach here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pivot table?

[image]

I have Swedish Excel so it's "," for numbers here.
But is this what you need?
Pivot table settings:

[image]

Old style:

[image]

```
F2:
=Sumif($A$2:$A$5,A2,$C$2:$C$5)+Sumif($A$2:$A$5,A2,$D$2:$D$5)

G2:
=F2/countif($A$2:$A$5;A2)
```

Comment: I Think i need formula fields rather than using the Pivot Table

Comment: @CodeMonger Updated answer

Comment: Thanks not to be a pain but i think you might have been right on the Pivot. How is the pivot updated. Meaning if you add a new row or update values i noticed it doesnt update the pivot.

Comment: You can make the pivot auto update on selection change. This can be good if you have a smal data set, but a pain if it's lots of rows and columns. Search for auto update pivot table and test it